# AppleScript to change Audio MIDI Settings

Tags: macos, audio, applescript, settings, midi

Quick and simple AppleScript question.
I need to have an applescript that ticks the checkbox in the Audio MIDI Setup application. I am completely new to applescript.
The dialog looks like this, I need to check the 2nd checkbox.

[image: Audio MIDI Setup window]

Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "I need to check the 2nd checkbox."? The only "check boxes" I see are directly under the Mute label.  Something tells me that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly those checkboxes under the Mute label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have "Soundflower" in my own system audio devices so I don't know I can get the exact values to create the AppleScript exactly the way you need it.  However, this script will select the second checkbox for "Built In Output".

---

[image]

---

Here is the script that will accomplish this:

```
tell application "Audio MIDI Setup"
activate
end tell
delay 2
try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Audio MIDI Setup"
            select row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Audio Devices" 

-- change the value in the beginning of that line from "select row 2" to "select row 3" This should select the "Soundflower Output Devicee"

            click checkbox 1 of UI element 4 of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Audio Devices"
        end tell
    end tell
end try
```

---